# How to get ChatGPT API to respond similarly to web version?

Tags: python, python-3.x, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I just started playing around with chatgpt api, and was wondering how I can receive a response paragraph similar to what's on the web?

Here is a sample:

```
s = "Who is Harry Potter?"
response = openai.Completion.create(model="text-davinci-003", prompt=s, temperature=0, max_tokens=7)

print(response)
```

This prints out:

```
  "choices": [
    {
      "finish_reason": "length",
      "index": 0,
      "logprobs": null,
      "text": "\n\nHarry Potter is a fictional"
    }
```

But on the openai website it gives a nice paragraph summarizing what I asked.

Does anyone know what the exact `temperature` and `max_tokens` parameters are for the website, so I can emulate it through their api?

Comment: You're using the Completion API, but ChatGPT itself uses the **Chat**Completion API. You are re-creating how GPT-**3** works, not *Chat*GPT. Here is how to use ChatCompletion: https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/chat

Comment: @RandomDavis I see, I've changed it to `ChatCompletion` with model `gpt-3.5-turbo`, but   the api only generates 1 paragraph, whereas if I prompt the website, it gives me 2 paragraphs with more detail. 

Is there a way to get the API to return more details like on the site?

Comment: It could be that your System prompt is different than what the website uses. I can't think what else would be different. I'm assuming you're keeping and sending the conversation history, so that's probably not an issue. I'm pretty sure the website also uses the `gpt-3.5-turbo` model but I'm not 100% sure. So, it might take some slight tweaking to get the output exactly how you expect.

Comment: @doejoe did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using Text Davinci 003 and this is not what ChatGPT runs on.

ChatGPT runs on 3.5 turbo. 
[As per documentation](https://platform.openai.com/docs/models/gpt-3-5), you can try using GPT 3.5 turbo. ([There are multiple versions too](https://platform.openai.com/docs/models/gpt-3-5))

That being said...

You are very unlikely to get the same exact results for both (or if you run the same query twice) as the LLM is a non-deterministic solution, meaning that the same input will return different results each time (unless they employ some sort of caching which I am not aware of).
Additionally, ChatGPT is constantly updated using newer versions of 3.5 turbo (you can see which version they're running at the bottom of the chat page). So you're probably going to be running on a different version of 3.5 turbo than the one they're using.

[More on non-deterministic algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_algorithm)

Comment: Per @RandomDavis I've changed it to use the `ChatCompletion()` and gpt turbo, but it returns only a single paragraph, whereas the website returns 2 paragraphs with more detail. Is there a way to have the api match what the website provides?

Comment: I won't ever (basically) return the same exact results for both as the LLM is a non-deterministic solution, meaning that the same input will return different results each time.

Comment: The answer it provides is an "approximation".
It's kinda like a chess engine, which may return different "best moves" each time a board position is given

Comment: Also look at this [link](https://platform.openai.com/docs/models/gpt-3-5):
The version of Gpt used for chatgpt is constantly updated.

Comment: Does this make sense?

Answer (score 3):

You specified 7 as the maximum number of tokens (max_tokens=7).
That is why the API provided a response of only one short sentence.